# Problems with Get / Set value to text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I'm trying to when I press button (Get Value) to set the size of checkboxes to text. I make the variable (numAll) global, and convert toString, but still not working. any idea to solve the solution?

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/62QY8/35/)

Jquery:

```
$(function () {
    // Click function to add a card
    var $div = $('<div />').addClass('sortable-div');
    $('<label>Title</label><br/>').appendTo($div);
    $('<input/>', {
        "type": "text",
            "class": "ctb"
    }).appendTo($div);
    $('<input/>', {
        "type": "text",
            "class": "date"
    }).appendTo($div);
    $('<input/>', { 
        "type": "text", 
            "class": "Cbox" 
    }).appendTo($div);
    var cnt = 0,
        $currentTarget;
    $('#AddCardBtn').click(function () {
        var $newDiv = $div.clone(true);
        cnt++;
        $newDiv.prop("id", "div" + cnt);

        $newDiv.data('checkboxes', []);

        $('#userAddedCard').append($newDiv);
        //      alert($('#userAddedCard').find("div.sortable-div").length);        
    });


    $("#Getbtn").on("click", function () {
        var val = $("#customTextBox").val();
        $currentTarget.find(".ctb").val(val);
        $currentTarget.find(".date").val($("#datepicker").val());

        var Cboxval = numAll;
        var st = console.toString(Cboxval);
        $currentTarget.find(".Cbox").val(st);

        $currentTarget.data('checkboxes', $('#modalDialog').data('checkboxes')); /* Copy checkbox data to card */

        //$('#modalDialog').dialog("close");
    });

     var numAll;

function updateProgress() {
    var numAll = $('input[type="checkbox"]').length;
    var numChecked = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;

    if (numAll > 0) {
        var perc = (numChecked / numAll) * 100;
        $("#progressbar").progressbar("value", perc)
        .children('.ui-progressbar-value')
        .html(perc.toPrecision(3) + '%')
        .css("display", "block");
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you seen your js console for any error messages?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Not seeing your Get Value button in your demo.

Comment: If I create fx. 5 checkboxes, then I want to get the value of (5) and set in text on the card. That is what I want to.

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to say you have to double click on the card

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `.toString()` method on a Number Object:

```
    var st = Cboxval.toString();
```

Otherwise I can't find where are you defining the `numAll` variable, so I had to replace

```
var Cboxval = numAll;
```

with:

```
var Cboxval = numAll === undefined ? 0 : numAll;
```

in order to be able to perform mys tests.

Here you have an updated version of your [JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/62QY8/38/).

Comment: You shoul define the `numAll` variable before calling it.

Comment: What do you mean? Can you provide some code to show your point?

Comment: Here you have a working demo in my answer (edited). Don't forget to mrk the answer as accepted and upvote it if you are satisfied with the post ;)

Comment: Thank you. I used the same code to implement for those checkboxes who are checked. I would like to set the value like this (5/3), in the same text. The number of 5 is the total number of created checkboxes, and the number of 3 is the checked checkboxes. Can you help me please? I have a demo, what I have implemented http://jsfiddle.net/62QY8/39/